# Finding SQL records bounded by a value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I would like to return the records for two records that bound a value. So if my value is 120, it lies between two records of 100 and 200. The question becomes how best to pull in the top two records. I've tried something along these lines but it causes issues because the bin sizes that define the range are not even.

So records are of the following type:

```
Value    ID
0        0
50       1
100      2
200      3
300      4
```

So if I'm looking for the bounds of the number 120, then by using the following code, I can generate:

```
DECLARE @Actual_Value int;
@Actual_Value = 120

SELECT TOP 2 * FROM table 
WHERE XX in YY and ZZ in AA
ORDER BY ABS( Table_Values - @Actual_Value )
```

And then I get the following:

50 and 100

rather than 100 and 200 which is logical and correct, because of the non uniform bin size. No I can do this in two passes, but is there a way to do it in one query only. I.e. the following works:

```
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM table 
WHERE XX in YY and ZZ in AA and Table_Values > @Actual_Value
ORDER BY ABS( Table_Values - @Actual_Value )

SELECT TOP 1 * FROM table 
WHERE XX in YY and ZZ in AA and Table_Values < @Actual_Value
ORDER BY ABS( Table_Values - @Actual_Value )
```

Is there a smart simple way to do this in SQL? Rather than two queries?

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: What if the value is exactly one of the bounds?

Answer (score 0):

`abs(50-120) = 70` which is less than `abs(200-120) = 80`

try something like this instead:

```
with ins as (
select * 
     , ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by sign(table_value-@actual_value) order by abs(table_value-@actual_value)) as cand
from   table_name
where  xx in yy and zz in aa
)
select *
  from ins
 where cand = 1
```

Comment: True, that why it fails because the bin sizes are not uniform.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Answer (score 0):

In sqlserver 2012:

```
SELECT value,next FROM
(SELECT value, LEAD(value,1) OVER(ORDER BY value) next FROM table) t
WHERE @Actual_Value BETWEEN value AND next
```

Comment: Nope, that's why I asked. It's available from 2012

Answer (score 0):

you can make the "bin sizes" consecutive by using rank function, and with a self-join, for instance, detect the 2 consecutive bins like this:

```
SELECT a.value, b.value FROM 
(
(SELECT value, RANK() OVER (ORDER BY value) RANK FROM table) a 
JOIN (SELECT value, RANK() OVER (ORDER BY value) RANK FROM table) b 
ON a.rank=b.rank-1
) WHERE @Actual_Value BETWEEN a.value AND b.value
```